# Angular Subscribe Undefined Problem with Validation

Tags: angular, typescript, subscribe

At the beginning I want to say that I know there are a lot of questions about it but none of them had the exact problem I had. I've tried many things with map and stuff but actually don't know what's the right way.

First of all I want to use it for a opportunity to edit the userProfile. The input fields should be loaded with the current values of the profile. That I want to do through the validators to don't have any validation errors.

So in the `constructor()` of my `profile.component.ts` I call this method:

```js
readProfileData() {
 this.userService.getProfile()
   .pipe(first())
   .subscribe(
     userData => {
       this.firstname = userData.firstName;
       this.lastname = userData.lastName;
       this.username = userData.username;
       this.email = userData.email;
       this.dateOfBirth = userData.dateOfBirth;
       this.country = userData.location;
       this.profileImage = userData.profileImage;
       this.gender = userData.gender;
       this.lastUpdated = userData.lastUpdated;
       this.activated = userData.activated;
       this.userId = userData.userId;
       this.userService.profileImageUpdate$.next(this.profileImage);
     });
}
```

The method `getProfile()` get called:

```js
getProfile() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.GET_PROFILE_API);
}
```

In my `ngOnInit()` method I call the form build:

```js
public buildForm() {
 this.editForm = this.form.group({
   username: [this.username, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(this.minLength), CustomValidators.validateCharacters], AlreadyTakenValidator.checkUsername(this.registrationService)],
   email: [this.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email, CustomValidators.validateCharacters], AlreadyTakenValidator.checkEmail(this.registrationService)],
   oldPassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
   newPassword: ['', [Validators.required]],
   newPasswordConf: ['', [Validators.required]],
   firstname: [this.firstname, [Validators.required, NoWhitespaceValidator()]],
   lastname: [this.lastname, [Validators.required, NoWhitespaceValidator()]],
   country: ['', [Validators.required]],
   dateOfBirth: ['', [Validators.required]],
   gender: ['', [Validators.required]],
 }
 , {
     validator: MustMatch('newPassword', 'newPasswordConf')
   })
}
```

So and now as you can imagine the problem is that no values are shown in the input fields because they are undefined. If I write my own values directly in the field before the validator it works. So it's the subscribe problem. I actually need the variables to get filled.

I've read so many things with map to res.json or something with toPromise but nothing that helped me. I understand to problem that it is async and not loaded already but I don't know how to prevent it without let the user stuck in the loading progress.

Comment: subscribe is async, soo you don't know when the callback fire, you need to do -> this.editForm.patchValue({username : this..username,...all the fields than need to be patched on the form}) inside the subscribe

Answer (score 1):

How about we delegate the responsibility of generating the form to the service.

So the service will:

1. Get the data from the API.
2. Generate the form.
3. Populate the form with the data that it has fetched.
4. Return the form.

The component will just consume the form. Keeping that in mind, here's how you'd implement the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  GET_PROFILE_API = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1';

  constructor(
    private readonly http: HttpClient,
    private readonly fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  getUserForm() {
    return this.getProfile()
      .pipe(
        map(userProfile => this.generateUserForm(userProfile))
      );
  }

  private generateUserForm(user) {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: [user.name, Validators.required],
      username: [user.username, Validators.required],
      email: [user.email, Validators.required],
      phone: [user.phone, Validators.required],
      website: [user.website, Validators.required],
    });
  }

  private getProfile() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.GET_PROFILE_API);
  }

}
```

Your Component will then look something like this:

Template:

```
<form 
  *ngIf="form$ | async as form" 
  [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Phone">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Website</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="website" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Website">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And Component Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form$: Observable<FormGroup>;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form$ = this.userService.getUserForm();
  }

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/delegate-form-building-to-service?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: I think this works but I need to access the form `get f() {
    return this.editForm.controls;
  }` and also for a autocomplete filter for countries. With the observable that does not seem to be possible.

Comment: You do have the `form` in your template, right? So you can use `form.controls` right in your template. If you have many such instances where access to the form is required in multiple PnCs, then instead of unwrapping the Observable in the template using an `async` pipe,  you can `subscribe` to it in your TS Class and go from there.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand you. Yes I also have this form in my template. But I dont know how I should use it when it does not even get loaded anywhere. With your second suggestion you mean the thing that yanky_cranky in the answer below means with async-await or am I wrong?

Comment: so the form works now but I get no errors shown. When i delete fields or touch fields that are for example empty I see red fields but no error message is shown nowhere. Your StackBlitz example does also not react on validation.

Comment: Okay when I change the *ngIf for the error to: `*ngIf="editForm.get('email').hasError('required')"`the message gets shown. But with my normal `*ngIf="f.email.touched && f.email.errors && f.email.errors.required"` he recognizes the error but no message is shown.

Comment: Use it like this:

`form.controls['username'].errors?.required` I've updated the stackblitz accordingly.

Comment: Okay this works actually. I don't know why. Does this not do exactly the same: `get f() { return this.editForm.controls; }` why does it not work? Can you please explain me what you mean with "unwrapping the Observable in the template using an async pipe" so what I should do? I think to do it like you did is terrible for me. Also because I use for countries something like this `*ngFor="let option of filteredCountries | async"`

Comment: Because you don't have access to `editForm` on your Component Class. You only have it in your Template since you unwrapped the observable wrapping it, with an `async` pipe.

Also, yeah, I agree. My solution is not a fit-all solution. I just tried to answer based on the provided information :)

Comment: Okay I really don't understand what is going on there and what I'm actually doing that's terrible. Everywhere somebody says use async or promises and I have no idea how both work and do not find a good example.

Comment: Yes, that would be pretty nice if you could do this. I really need to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, this is happening because http.get is asynchronous in nature, that means, till the time you get values in your subscriber response, it would have already called your "buildForm()"

To Fix the same any of the followings can be done :

a) Call your "buildForm()" inside the subscription.

b) You can use async-await at method definition of "readProfileData()" , also await at function call of readProfileData() then call "buildForm()"

c) You can convert these into promise and resolve only when you receive your response

You can refer :

[deep-dive async-await](https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/async-await-in-typescript-tutorial)

[resolving promises](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/promises)